# Issues with Pulseaudio - combined output hdmi + analog

Tags: pulseaudio, hdmi

For a kiosk installation (Xubuntu) I need to have sound to output at the same time through HDMI and headphone jack on Dell Optiplex 7040 micro. The computer has an onboard card with analogue and digital profiles.

When using installation default config for pulseaudio the sound works as it is intended. However when I want to make custom configuration (autologin account which runs kiosk application) in user's .config/pulse/default.pa nothing works. If I copy default system configuration to the same directory all works again.

Output of `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3234 Analog [ALC3234 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I'd like to have a configuration in .config/pulse/default.pa file. I tried to follow any recommendation I found on creating combined sink unssuccessfully. This is what is proposed but somehow does not work for me.

```
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0 sink_name=analog
load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,3 sink_name=hdmi

#set-sink-port analog analog-output-headphones
#set-sink-volume analog 65536
#set-sink-volume hdmi 65536

load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined slaves=hdmi,analog
set-default-sink combined
```

Not even default.pa with first line is working for me.... Don't know what to do about it... Thanks for any useful recommendation in advanece.